# OpenCV: how to read .pfm files?

Tags: c++, opencv, readfile

Is there a way to read .pfm files in OpenCV?

Comment: Take a look at the code of http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pamtopfm.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the description of the ".pfm" file formate (see http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pfm.html), I wrote the following read/write functions, which only depend standard C/C++ library. It is proved to work well on reading/writing the pfm file, like, the ground truth disparity ".pfm" files from MiddleBury Computer Vision (see http://vision.middlebury.edu/stereo/submit3/).

```
#ifndef _PGM_H_
#define _PGM_H_
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <bitset>　/*std::bitset<32>*/
#include <cstdio>

enum PFM_endianness { BIG, LITTLE, ERROR};

class PFM {
public:
    PFM();
    inline bool is_little_big_endianness_swap(){
        if (this->endianess == 0.f) {
            std::cerr << "this-> endianness is not assigned yet!\n";
            exit(0);
        }
        else {
            uint32_t endianness = 0xdeadbeef;
            //std::cout << "\n" << std::bitset<32>(endianness) << std::endl;
            unsigned char * temp = (unsigned char *)&endianness;
            //std::cout << std::bitset<8>(*temp) << std::endl;
            PFM_endianness endianType_ = ((*temp) ^ 0xef == 0 ?
                LITTLE : (*temp) ^ (0xde) == 0 ? BIG : ERROR);
            // ".pfm" format file specifies that: 
            // positive scale means big endianess;
            // negative scale means little endianess.
            return  ((BIG == endianType_) && (this->endianess < 0.f))
                || ((LITTLE == endianType_) && (this->endianess > 0.f));
        }
    }


    template<typename T>
    T * read_pfm(const std::string & filename) {
        FILE * pFile;
        pFile = fopen(filename.c_str(), "rb");
        char c[100];
        if (pFile != NULL) {
            fscanf(pFile, "%s", c);
            // strcmp() returns 0 if they are equal.
            if (!strcmp(c, "Pf")) {
                fscanf(pFile, "%s", c);
                // atoi: ASCII to integer.
                // itoa: integer to ASCII.
                this->width = atoi(c);
                fscanf(pFile, "%s", c);
                this->height = atoi(c);
                int length_ = this->width * this->height;
                fscanf(pFile, "%s", c);
                this->endianess = atof(c);

                fseek(pFile, 0, SEEK_END);
                long lSize = ftell(pFile);
                long pos = lSize - this->width*this->height * sizeof(T);
                fseek(pFile, pos, SEEK_SET);

                T* img = new T[length_];
                //cout << "sizeof(T) = " << sizeof(T);
                fread(img, sizeof(T), length_, pFile);
                fclose(pFile);

                /* The raster is a sequence of pixels, packed one after another,
                 * with no delimiters of any kind. They are grouped by row,
                 * with the pixels in each row ordered left to right and
                 * the rows ordered bottom to top.
                 */
                T* tbimg = (T *)malloc(length_ * sizeof(T));// top-to-bottom.
                //PFM SPEC image stored bottom -> top reversing image                                           
                for (int i = 0; i < this->height; i++) {
                    memcpy(&tbimg[(this->height - i - 1)*(this->width)],
                        &img[(i*(this->width))],
                        (this->width) * sizeof(T));
                }


                if (this->is_little_big_endianness_swap()){
                    std::cout << "little-big endianness transformation is needed.\n";
                    // little-big endianness transformation is needed.
                    union {
                        T f;
                        unsigned char u8[sizeof(T)];
                    } source, dest;

                    for (int i = 0; i < length_; ++i) {
                        source.f = tbimg[i];
                        for (unsigned int k = 0, s_T = sizeof(T); k < s_T; k++)
                            dest.u8[k] = source.u8[s_T - k - 1];
                        tbimg[i] = dest.f;
                        //cout << dest.f << ", ";
                    }
                }
                delete[] img;
                return tbimg;

            }
            else {
                std::cout << "Invalid magic number!"
                    << " No Pf (meaning grayscale pfm) is missing!!\n";
                fclose(pFile);
                exit(0);
            }

        }
        else {
            std::cout << "Cannot open file " << filename
                << ", or it does not exist!\n";
            fclose(pFile);
            exit(0);
        }

    }

    template<typename T>
    void write_pfm(const std::string & filename, const T* imgbuffer, 
        const float & endianess_) {
        std::ofstream ofs(filename.c_str(), std::ifstream::binary);
        // ** 1) Identifier Line: The identifier line contains the characters 
        // "PF" or "Pf". PF means it's a color PFM. 
        // Pf means it's a grayscale PFM.
        // ** 2) Dimensions Line:
        // The dimensions line contains two positive decimal integers, 
        // separated by a blank. The first is the width of the image; 
        // the second is the height. Both are in pixels.
        // ** 3) Scale Factor / Endianness:
        // The Scale Factor / Endianness line is a queer line that jams 
        // endianness information into an otherwise sane description 
        // of a scale. The line consists of a nonzero decimal number, 
        // not necessarily an integer. If the number is negative, that 
        // means the PFM raster is little endian. Otherwise, it is big 
        // endian. The absolute value of the number is the scale 
        // factor for the image.
        // The scale factor tells the units of the samples in the raster.
        // You use somehow it along with some separately understood unit 
        // information to turn a sample value into something meaningful, 
        // such as watts per square meter.

        ofs << "Pf\n"
            << this->width << " " << this->height << "\n"
            << endianess_ << "\n";
        /* PFM raster:
         * The raster is a sequence of pixels, packed one after another,
         * with no delimiters of any kind. They are grouped by row,
         * with the pixels in each row ordered left to right and
         * the rows ordered bottom to top.
         * Each pixel consists of 1 or 3 samples, packed one after another,
         * with no delimiters of any kind. 1 sample for a grayscale PFM
         * and 3 for a color PFM (see the Identifier Line of the PFM header).
         * Each sample consists of 4 consecutive bytes. The bytes represent
         * a 32 bit string, in either big endian or little endian format,
         * as determined by the Scale Factor / Endianness line of the PFM
         * header. That string is an IEEE 32 bit floating point number code.
         * Since that's the same format that most CPUs and compiler use,
         * you can usually just make a program use the bytes directly
         * as a floating point number, after taking care of the
         * endianness variation.
         */
        int length_ = this->width*this->height;
        this->endianess = endianess_;
        T* tbimg = (T *)malloc(length_ * sizeof(T));
        // PFM SPEC image stored bottom -> top reversing image
        for (int i = 0; i < this->height; i++) {
            memcpy(&tbimg[(this->height - i - 1)*this->width],
                &imgbuffer[(i*this->width)],
                this->width * sizeof(T));
        }

        if (this->is_little_big_endianness_swap()) {
            std::cout << "little-big endianness transformation is needed.\n";
            // little-big endianness transformation is needed.
            union {
                T f;
                unsigned char u8[sizeof(T)];
            } source, dest;

            for (int i = 0; i < length_; ++i) {
                source.f = tbimg[i];
                for (size_t k = 0, s_T = sizeof(T); k < s_T; k++)
                    dest.u8[k] = source.u8[s_T - k - 1];
                tbimg[i] = dest.f;
                //cout << dest.f << ", ";
            }
        }

        ofs.write((char *)tbimg, this->width*this->height * sizeof(T));
        ofs.close();
        free(tbimg);
    }

    inline float getEndianess(){return endianess;}
    inline int getHeight(void){return height;}
    inline int getWidth(void){return width;}
    inline void setHeight(const int & h){height = h;}
    inline void setWidth(const int & w){width = w;}
private:
    int height;
    int width;
    float endianess;
};

#endif /* PGM_H_ */
```

Forgive me to leave lots of useless comments in the code.

A simple example shows the write/read:

```
    int main(){
        PFM pfm_rw;
        string temp = "img/Motorcycle/disp0GT.pfm";
        float * p_disp_gt = pfm_rw.read_pfm<float>(temp);
        //int imgH = pfm_rw.getHeight();
        //int imgW = pfm_rw.getWidth();
        //float scale = pfm_rw.getEndianess();
        string temp2 = "result/Motorcycle/disp0GT_n1.pfm";
        pfm_rw.write_pfm<float>(temp2, p_disp_gt, -1.0f);
        return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

PFM is an uncommon image format and I don't know why the Middlebury dataset chose to use that, probably because it uses floating point values.
Anyway I was able to read the images with OpenCV:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

groundtruth = cv2.imread('disp0.pfm', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
```

Note the `IMREAD_UNCHANGED` flag. Somehow it is able to read all the correct values even if OpenCV does not support it.

But *wait a minute*: `inf` values are commonly used to set INVALID pixel disparity, so to properly display the image you should do:

```
# Remove infinite value to display
groundtruth[groundtruth==np.inf] = 0

# Normalize and convert to uint8
groundtruth = cv2.normalize(groundtruth, None, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX).astype(np.uint8)

# Show
cv2.imshow("groundtruth", groundtruth)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, OpenCV doesn't support to read PFM files directly.

You can refer to the code snippet [**here**](https://wordgems.wordpress.com/2010/12/14/quick-dirty-pfm-reader/) for a simple PFM reader, which will enable you to read PFM files into `COLOR *data` with `COLOR` defined as follows:

```
typedef struct {
    float r;
    float g;
    float b;
} COLOR;
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Thanks for the information. +1.